# How do I call an additional function based on which HTML element triggered a common handler?

Tags: jquery, html, select, event-handling

I have a common event handler for my select buttons :

My code is :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){$("#delAppSelectApp,#userAppSelectApp,#hexSelectApp,#countSelectApp").change(function(){
    ......
    });});
```

How would I call an additional function if changing "countSelectApp" select triggered the 
common handler.

I tried using

```
    alert(this.toSource())
```

to ascertain which select triggered the handler, but all I get is an alert saying

```
    [object HTMLelement]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your event handler jQuery sets `this` to be the DOM element that the event applies to, so you can directly access any properties or methods apply to DOM events, or you can wrap it in a jQuery call as `$(this)` to access jQuery methods.

So in my opinion the simplest (and certainly most efficient) way to test whether it was "countSelectApp" that the event applied to is just to use `this.id`:

```
if (this.id === "countSelectApp") {
   // call your function here
}
```

Incidentally, rather than list all the element ids in your jQuery selector I'd be inclined to give those elements a common class, say "selectApp", and then bind the change handler using class as a selector:

```
$(".selectApp").change(function() {
   if (this.id === "countSelectApp") {
      // call your function here
   }
...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

ask :

```
if($(this).attr('id')=="countSelectApp")
     callYourFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) as;

```
$('selector').change(function(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
});
```